# Get Specific Value From API

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
<?php
$apiKey = "*****";
$symbol = "XAU";
$curr = "USD";
$date = "";
$myHeaders = array(
'x-access-token: ' . $apiKey,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$curl = curl_init();
  $url = "https://www.goldapi.io/api/{$symbol}/{$curr}{$date}";
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $myHeaders
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($error) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $error;
} else {
echo $response; 
}
?>
```

I'm doing a live gold price app. from API I get all the data but what I want is how to get single data from the API response like low_price/timestamp, and how can I make it like live without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch data from a server without refreshing the page you can use ajax.

```
$(
document).ready(function() {
    var apiKey = "*****"; // Replace with your actual API key
    var symbol = "XAU";
    var curr = "USD";
    var date = ""; // Adjust if necessary

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.goldapi.io/api/" + symbol + "/" + curr + date,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            'x-access-token': apiKey,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response); // Outputs the response in the console
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error); // Outputs the error in the console
        }
    });
});
```

this code uses jquery and writes the response from api to console (ctrl + shift + i then console tab) and you have to load jquery first. alternatively you can use ajax to query your own API wrapper so you wont need to send your api key to user's browser